# How to plot floating point system with matlab

Tags: matlab, math, floating-point, computer-science

Consider a normalized floating point system of base 3, precision=3 and -1 <= e <= 1.
Since there are too many points to plot manually, how can I plot all the numbers in the system on a base 10 real axis with numbers that can be expressed exactly with MATLAB? Thankyou.

Comment: What do you mean by R3(3,1)?

Comment: sorry for been unspecific, I mean base = 3 and precision = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution also includes *subnormal* values.  I'm not sure if you wanted to include those.

```
close all
figure
hold on

base = 3;
prec = 3;

maxval = base ^ prec - 1;
mantissas = (-maxval: maxval) / (maxval + 1)

for expo = -prec: prec
    nums = mantissas * base ^ expo;
    plot(nums, 0, 'b.')
end
```

Further, this may not qualify as *exact*.  `MATLAB` ultimately converts all floating point values to a binary system.  Then, it plots on a screen with discretized pixel positions.  I don't think anything can overcome these limitations.

EDIT

After testing with base 10, I found an off-by-one error.  The `mantissas` should be divided by `(maxval + 1)` instead of `maxval`.